# Counting the occurence of a word in a collection of files in Linux

Tags: linux, word-count

I am trying to find the word count of a specific word in a collection of documents, in Linux.

I have tried with `grep` and `ack-grep` in combination with `wc` but I can't seem to come up with a valid combination of pipes :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
grep -o "string" filename | wc -w
```

If you want all files in a directory, run the following script from that directory:

```
for file in *
    do let count=$count+`grep -o "wordyouaretryingtofind" $file | wc -w`
done
echo occurence $count times
```

Comment: Cheers; I was missing that `-o` argument

Comment: Added something you might like